# C++, replace the i-th element with n elements (low complexity)

Tags: c++, vector, replace

Suppose two vectors:

```
std::vector<int> v1{1, 10, 18, 41, 6};
std::vector<int> v2{-12, 107, 14, -3, 5};
```

How to replace the i-th element of v1 with v2? For example

```
v1[2]<-v2
```

leads to

```
v1={1, 10, -12, 107, 14, -3, 5 , 41, 6}
```

The simple solution is:

```
v1[2] = v2[0]
v1.insert(v1.begin() + 3, v2.begin() + 1, v2.end())
```

Is there any faster (lower time complexity) method? Is it possible to perform these operations as a single statement?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're not going to get any faster.  It's an O(N) operation and that is what you are doing.  You can put it into a function so it only looks like one line of code.

Comment: `v1.insert(v1.begin() + 3, v2.begin(), v2.end())` should work. Just removing the first step of copying the first element of v2. Otherwise not much optimization.

Comment: `std::list` is faster (complexity wise). But you need to profile for the required workloads

Comment: If you have to often add/remove element(s) to use a list rather than a vector is faster, but of course all depend on what else you do with your sequence, vector and list have their own advantages and disadvantages

Comment: one line: `v1.insert(v1.emplace(v1.begin() + 2, v2.front()) + 1, v2.begin() + 1, v2.end());` ... unreadable and error-prone, not faster, if you want to use it you should at least encapsulate it in a method like replace_and_insert or something similar

Comment: [`std::list::splice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) has constant time complexity, but `std::vector` doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: If you need a vector then I would append the inserted vector and do a rotate. This would avoid the repeated moving of the elements following the insertion point.

Comment: Thanks for your comments...